# How does GHC/Haskell decide what character encoding it's going to decode/encode from/to?

Tags: haskell, character-encoding, ghc

It seems that GHC is at least inconsistent in the character encoding it decides to decode from.

Consider a file, `omatase-shimashita.txt`, with the following content, encoded in UTF-8: お待たせしました

`readFile` seems to read this in properly...

```
Prelude> content <- readFile "/home/chris/Desktop/omatase-shimashita.txt"
Prelude> length content
8
Prelude> putStrLn content
お待たせしました
```

However, if I write a simple "echo" server, it does not decode with a default of UTF-8.  Consider the following code that handles an incoming client:

```
handleClient handle = do
  line <- hGetLine handle
  putStrLn $ "Read following line: " ++ toString line
  handleClient handle
```

And the relevant client code, explicitly sending UTF-8:

```
Data.ByteString.hPutStrLn handle $ Codec.Binary.UTF8.Generic.fromString "お待たせしました"
```

Is this not inconsistent behavior?  Is there any method to this madness?  I am planning to rewrite my application(s) to explicitly use `ByteString` objects and explicitly encode and decode using `Codec.Binary.UTF8`, but it would be good to know what's going on here anyway...  :o/

UPDATE: I am running on Ubuntu Linux, version 10.10, with a locale of en_US.UTF-8...

```
$ cat /etc/default/locale 
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
$ echo $LANG 
en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: In the end I used `Codec.Binary.UTF8` to encode/decode and `Data.ByteString` to send/receive the raw bytes.  Presumably chrisdb's solution should work, though; for me, it worked when I tested it with my toy server/client, but was not working when I tried it on my real-world app (which was probably due to my missing some detail, but I got impatient and went with the `ByteString` approach).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which version of GHC are you using? Older versions especially didn't do unicode I/O very well.

This section in the GHC documentation describes how to change input/output encodings:

http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/System-IO.html#23

Also, the documentation says this:

> A text-mode Handle has an associated
>   TextEncoding, which is used to decode
>   bytes into Unicode characters when
>   reading, and encode Unicode characters
>   into bytes when writing.
>
> The default TextEncoding is the same
>   as the default encoding on your
>   system, which is also available as
>   localeEncoding. (GHC note: on Windows,
>   we currently do not support
>   double-byte encodings; if the
>   console's code page is unsupported,
>   then localeEncoding will be latin1.)
>
> Encoding and decoding errors are
>   always detected and reported, except
>   during lazy I/O (hGetContents,
>   getContents, and readFile), where a
>   decoding error merely results in
>   termination of the character stream,
>   as with other I/O errors.

Maybe this has something to do with your problem? If GHC has defaulted to something other than utf-8 somewhere, or your handle has been manually set to use a different encoding, that might explain the problem. If you're just trying to echo text at the console, then probably some kind of console code-page funniness is going on. I know I've had similar problems in the past with other languages like Python and printing unicode in a windows console.

Try running `hSetEncoding handle utf8` and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Summary: if you're echoing to the console/stdout, it's probably something to do with your system default encoding, or GHC defaulting to latin1 on windows.

Comment: FYI, it is not a Windows problem, and I don't think it's a terminal-specific problem either.  I'm running on Ubuntu with a locale of en_US.UTF-8.  `cat /etc/default/locale` yields `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`, and `echo $LANG` yields `en_US.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 6):

Your first example uses the standard IO library, `System.IO`.  Operations in this library use the default system encoding (also known as `localeEncoding`) unless you specify otherwise.  Presumably your system is set up to use UTF-8, so that is the encoding used by `putStrLn`, `hGetContents` and so on.

Your second example uses `Data.ByteString`.  Since this library deals in sequences of bytes only, it does no encoding or decoding.  So `Data.ByteString.hGetLine` converts the bytes in the file directly to a `ByteString`.

The best way to do text I/O in general is to use the [text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) package.

Comment: Yes, I understand the difference between a standard character `String` and a `ByteString`...  I was just pointing out that I was definitely sending UTF-8-encoded text across the wire -- but, for whatever reason, the recipient (using `System.IO.hGetLine`) was not decoding using UTF-8.