# haskell - invalid code page byte sequence

Tags: file, haskell, utf-8

```
readFile "file.html"
"start of the file... *** Exception: file.html: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid code page byte sequence)
```

It's a UTF-8 file created with notepad++... how can I read the file in haskell?

Comment: Can you perhaps post a hex dump of a minimal file that shows this error for you?  I can't duplicate your error.

Comment: What is your locale? Is it a utf-8 one or something ucs2ish (notepad++ suggests Windows)?

Comment: It's windows.. no idea about my locale (meaning: if possible, I wouldn't like to change it)

Comment: Are there BOM marks (0xFE 0xFF) at the start of the file? Could you post hexdump of the start of the file (say 0x100 bytes)?

Comment: yes, there are BOM marks. just BOM mark and that one character. `EF BB BF C4 8D 0D`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By default, files are read in the system locale, so if you have a file using a non-standard encoding, you need to set the encoding of the file handle yourself.

```
foo = do
    handle <- openFile "file.html" ReadMode
    hSetEncoding handle utf8_bom
    contents <- hGetContents handle
    doSomethingWithContents
    hClose handle
```

should get you started. Note that this contains no error handling, the better way would thus be

```
import Control.Exception -- for bracket

foo = bracket
        (openFile "file.html" ReadMode >>= \h -> hSetEncoding h utf8_bom >> return h)
        hClose
        (\h -> hGetContents h >>= doSomething)
```

or

```
foo = withFile "file.html" ReadMode $
        \h -> do hSetEncoding h utf8_bom
                 contents <- hGetContents h
                 doSomethingWith contents
```

Comment: I came up with something similar (like your `foo` example, though I didn't know about `_bom`..). Is it possible to do the computation outside, like the way I do it with `readFile`? the `foo` example works if I don't use the `hClose` line (and it's OK for my toy program, but would like to know the "right way".. do I have to return something like `IO (String, Handle)`? )

Comment: It's a bit difficult, if you need your file to be read lazily. The `hClose` closes the file when the computation returns, that may happen before anything of the file is read. So if you can have the entire file in memory at once, doing a simple ``length contents `seq` return contents`` would force reading the entire file and you can do the processing outside. Otherwise, it would probably be best to read the file as a lazy `ByteString` and convert from that (using `Data.ByteString.Lazy.UTF8.toString` from the `utf8-string` package).

Comment: I don't see how `ByteString` helps / makes things easier (though I'm a beginner).. `readFile` is lazy, right? So how does it close the file? Does it check that the last character was read? Could I imitate it's behaviour somehow?

Comment: `readFile` does a bit of magic, it puts the file-handle in semi-closed state, and it is only truly closed after the end of file is reached. `Data.ByteString.Lazy`'s `readFile` does that too. You can imitate that behaviour, but you'd need to use low-level file-handle operations for that, I would put that off for a while. Using lazy `ByteString`s would allow you to read the file lazily (they don't care about encoding, in contrast to the `String` API), and consume it incrementally. If the file is small enough, forcing it to be read entirely before returning its contents is easier.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi), your 6 bytes decode as follows:

```
EF BB BF -> ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE (i.e. the BOM, although its not needed in UTF-8
C4 8D    -> LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CARON (what you said)
0D       -> CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)
```

So its a legal UTF-8 sequence.

However the standard Prelude functions originally just did ASCII. I don't know what they do now, but see this question [How does GHC/Haskell decide what character encoding it's going to decode/encode from/to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286860/how-does-ghc-haskell-decide-what-character-encoding-its-going-to-decode-encode) for some more ideas.  And then use http://hackage.haskell.org/package/utf8-string instead of the Prelude functions.