# Problems with Character Encoding Using Haskells Text.Pandoc

Tags: haskell, encoding, pandoc

I want to parse a LaTeX-File using Pandoc and output the text, like this:

```
import qualified Text.Pandoc as P
import Text.Pandoc.Error (handleError)

tex2Str = do 
           file <- readFile "test.tex"
           let p = handleError $ P.readLaTeX P.def file
           writeFile "A.txt" $  P.writePlain P.def p
           writeFile "B.txt" $  file
```

While the encoding in file B.txt seems to be "right" (i.e. uft-8), the encoding in file A.txt is not correct.

Here the respective extracts of the files:

A.txt:

`...
Der _Crawler_ lÃ¤uft hierbei Ã¼ber die Dokumentenbasis
...`

B.txt: 

`...
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
...
Der \emph{Crawler} läuft hierbei über die Dokumentenbasis
...`

Anyone knows how to fix this? Why does Pandoc use the wrong encoding (I thought, it uses utf-8 by default)?

**Update**:

I got a (partial) solution: Using the `readFile` and `writeFile`-Functions from `Text.Pandoc.UTF8` seems to fix some of the problems, i.e.

```
import qualified Text.Pandoc as P
import Text.Pandoc.Error (handleError)
import qualified Text.Pandoc.UTF8 as UTF (readFile, writeFile)

tex2Str = do 
            file <- UTF.readFile "test.tex"
            let p = handleError $ P.readLaTeX P.def file
            UTF.writeFile "A.txt" $  P.writePlain P.def p
            UTF.writeFile "B.txt" $  file
```

However, I still didnt get the clue what the actual problem was, since both `Prelude.readFile` and `Prelude.writeFile` seem to work uft8-aware...

Comment: I guess you've solved the problem already. I was going to ask: What encoding is `test.tex`? And what value do you get for `getLocaleEncoding` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/GHC-IO-Encoding.html#v:getLocaleEncoding)? I suspect one or the other isn't UTF-8.

Comment: see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5288816/214446) about how GHC does character encoding... basically it seems to use the default system encoding.

Comment: btw, feel free to post your solution as an answer...