# Haskell and the web (UTF-8)

Tags: haskell, web, utf-8

I have a Haskell-Script what `putStr` some stuff ... and this output I want to display on a webpage. I compiled the Haskellscript and let it be executed like a CGI Script, works well.

But when I have special characters in the `putStr`, it will fail:

Terminal-Output:

```
<p class="text">what happrns at ä ?</p>
```

Web output:

```
what happrns at
```

And nothing behind it is displayed ... wha happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some questions:

1. What `Content-type` header is your CGI script sending?
2. Are you setting the encoding on the `stdout` handle?

You should always send a `Content-type` header, and in that header you can stipulate the character encoding. See [this page](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index) for more details.

Also, the encoding for Haskell file handles is determined by your OS's current default. It might be UTF-8, but it also might be something else. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5288816/866915) for more info.

So to make sure that the characters you send appear correctly on a web page, I would:

1. Send a `Content-type` header with charset=utf8
2. Make sure the encoding for `stdout` is also set to `utf8`:

   ```
   import System.IO
   ...
   hSetEncoding stdout utf8
   ```

If the Content-type header and your output encoding agree, things should work out.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot `hSetEncoding`, this was the important thing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the Haskell program is properly outputting utf-8, you will still need to let the browser know what encoding you are using.  In HTML 4, you can do this as follows

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

(add this inside the <head> tag).

In HTML 5 you can use

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

---

You can verify that the Haskell program is outputting the correct format using xxd on the command line

```
./myProgram | xxd
```

This will show you the actual output in bytes, so that you can verify on a character by character basis.

Comment: I have already `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in my `index.html`, what do you mean with ädd this inside the tag"?

Comment: Sorry, was supposed to be the `<head>` tag, but the output cut that.  I've fixed the response.  What was the result of viewing the xxd output?